# JS function working in console but not onClick event in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I'm wondering what's wrong with my code but can't figure out what's going on.

Here is the JS

```
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
let newTranslate = 0

const next = () => {
    newTranslate -= 100
    slider.style.transform = `translateX(${newTranslate}%)`
};

const prev = () => {
    newTranslate += 100
    slider.style.transform = `translateX(${newTranslate}%)`
};
```

and my HTML

```
 <section class="quote">
        <a onclick="prev()">
            <i class="arrow arrow-left"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="slider-container slider-1">
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slide slide-1">
                    <div class="quote_container">
                      ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <a onclick="next()">
          <i class="arrow arrow-right"></i>
     </a>
 </section>
```

What is strange is that `next()` is working good but `prev()` only working once after the page is loaded. When I click `next()` and then `prev()`, `prev()` is not working.

When I run the function in the console it's working perfectly.

It seems there is no async element so I don't understand at all.

Someone could help?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is wrong with `<input type="range">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because your slider element is above the left arrow (prev()) in the stack, so when it shifts left it sits on top and thus blocks your click. Just set the links to be `position:relative` with a `z-index:1` (or higher than the slider) and it should work

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
let newTranslate = 0

const next = () => {
  newTranslate -= 100
  slider.style.transform = `translateX(${newTranslate}%)`
};

const prev = () => {
  newTranslate += 100
  slider.style.transform = `translateX(${newTranslate}%)`
};
```

```css
.slider-container {
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

.quote a {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="quote">
  <a onclick="prev()">
    <i class="arrow arrow-left">left</i>
  </a>
  <div class="slider-container slider-1">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide slide-1">
        <div class="quote_container">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a onclick="next()">
    <i class="arrow arrow-right">right</i>
  </a>
</section>
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for your help !! So obvious after being said

Answer (score -1):

It might width parent tag is not enough to move the icon. Also with the slider element, I think u using the id for that element if right u missing the '#' prefix. It should be:

```
const slider = document.querySelector("#slider");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I target with class .slider.
The icon is just arrow to the slider.